# Error when copying the file into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hadoop cluster started normally and JPS shows datanodes and tasktracker running correctly. 
When i copy a file into HDFS this is the error message i am getting.

```
hduser@nn:~$ hadoop fs -put gettysburg.txt /user/hduser/getty/gettysburg.txt

Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
14/08/24 21:12:50 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:51 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:52 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:53 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:54 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:55 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:56 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:57 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:58 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/08/24 21:12:59 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: nn/10.10.1.1:54310. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to nn/10.10.1.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
hduser@nn:~$
```

I am able to do ssh from NN to DNs and Viceverssa and between DNs.

---

I have changed the cd /etc/hosts in all NNs and DNs as below.

```
#127.0.0.1      localhost loghost localhost.project1.ch-geni-net.emulab.net
#10.10.1.1      NN-Lan NN-0 NN
#10.10.1.2      DN1-Lan DN1-0 DN1
#10.10.1.3      DN2-Lan DN2-0 DN2
#10.10.1.5      DN4-Lan DN4-0 DN4
#10.10.1.4      DN3-Lan DN3-0 DN3
10.10.1.1       nn
10.10.1.2       dn1
10.10.1.3       dn2
10.10.1.4       dn3
10.10.1.5       dn4
```

---

My mapredsite.xml looks like this.

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
<description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://nn:54310</value>
<description>The name of the default file system. A URI whose scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation. The uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHE$
</property>
</configuration>
```

---

Configured cd /usr/local/hadoop/conf/master

```
hduser@nn:/usr/local/hadoop/conf$ vi masters 

#localhost
nn
```

---

```
hduser@dn1:~$ jps
9975 DataNode
10186 Jps
10070 TaskTracker
hduser@dn1:~$ 

hduser@nn:~$ jps
5979 JobTracker
5891 SecondaryNameNode
6159 Jps
hduser@nn:~$
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide your core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and yarn-site.xml. Which hadoop version are you trying?

Comment: and please check all services (especially nn node) are all available. attach your "jps" output.

Comment: I have added core-site.xml filehduser@nn:~$ jps
5979 JobTracker
5891 SecondaryNameNode
6159 Jps  
hduser@nn:~$    hduser@dn1:~$ jps
9975 DataNode
10186 Jps
10070 TaskTracker
hduser@dn1:~$

Answer (score 0):

Check your fs.default.name property in core-site.xml file. The value should be hdfs://NN:port.

Comment: changed to hdfs://NN:54310 couldnt fix the issue !!

Comment: tell your exact hadoop version.And make sure before starting hadoop after changing conf files you should format and clear tmp directory files.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following :

1. core-site.xml - the hdfs url mentioned - hdfs://ip:port
2. Format namenode
3. Check if safemode is on

Comment: I have changed the nn host name to IP address as hdfs://10.1.1.1:54310 in core.site.xml but it couldnt fix the problem